# WSO2 - Add field to an existing json

Tags: json, wso2

I'm trying to update an existing Json file and add a field on it to send to an endpoint, this is the example: 
Existing Json:

```
{
    "description": "FirstAttempt",
    "user": "Mark Red",
    "user-id": "123456",
    "classes": [{
        "name": "Math",
        "code": 12
    }],
    "votes": {
        "grammar": "9"

    },
    "average": {}
}
```

now, i need to add the field "nationality" in a sequence on WSO2, to get a result like this:

```
{
    "description": "FirstAttempt",
    "user": "Mark Red",
    "user-id": "123456",
    "nationality": "Italian",
    "classes": [{
        "name": "Math",
        "code": 12
    }],
    "votes": {
        "grammar": "9"

    },
    "average": {}
}
```

the solution that i found is

```
            <property name="nationalityJson" value="Italian" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.user)" name="userJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.country)" name="countryJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.user-id)" name="userIdJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($[0].classes)" name="classesJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($votes)" name="votesJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.average)" name="averageJson" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{
                          "description":"$1",
                          "user":"$2",
                          "user-id":"$3",
                          "nationality":"$4",   
                          "classes":$5,   
                          "average":"$6"
                          }
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:descriptionJson"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:userJson"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:userIdJson"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:nationalityJson"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:classesJson"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:averageIdJson"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
```

I don't think my solution is very performant, as i also would like to don't make updates in a field if is not received (for example, in this way, if the field "user" is not present in the json that i receive, the PayloadFactory will enhance the "user" field to null).
Do you know some way or function just to add a field to a json without use the "json-eval" expression for every field?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue using the Enrich Mediator:

```
    <property name="nationality" value="italian" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" property="nationality" type="property"/>
        <target xpath="json-eval($.nationality)"/>
    </enrich>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" xpath="json-eval($)"/>
        <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>
```

This works to replace the value of "nationality" field, that must be present in the json that we want to update

Answer (score 0):

You can try manipulating the request payload with either a class mediator or script mediator in the in-sequence path.

Given below is a sample Script Mediator solution to append the `nationality` to the request payload

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="api--In">
    <!-- Print request payload -->
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="Payload" expression="json-eval($.)" />
    </log>

    <!-- script mediator to append the nationality key -->
    <script language="js">
        <![CDATA[
            importPackage(Packages.java.util);
            var jsonPayload = mc.getPayloadJSON();

            var log = mc.getServiceLog();
            jsonPayload['nationality'] = 'Italian';
            log.info(JSON.stringify(jsonPayload));

            mc.setPayloadJSON(jsonPayload);
        ]]>
    </script>
</sequence>
```